# Are there discussions about developing a user contributed website?

Tags: user-engagement, contribute

I'm developing a website where users will be the ones who add new input, validate new suggestions and correct incorrect information. (Much like this site).

To make sure that abuse of these rights by users is minimized, I need to develop a good reputation system which encourages good behaviour, much like this site's reputation, again.

I would like to learn more about this subject, which is why I ask: are there any discussions about the development of user contributed websites? Any resources, studies or anything else that could help me out to develop a system that will work?

Thanks in advance.
- Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good google tech talk about [Building web reputation systems](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yn7e0J9m6rE)

[Yahoo patterns](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/social/people/reputation/) has a section on different reputation systems.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Meta sites associated with the StackExchange network of sites. The [meta site for the StackExchange itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) it probably the best place to start.